# Least squares in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, least-squares

A deployment of some (20 or so) sensors has detected a signal arriving from a certain direction. The sensors inter-distance is 50 meters. The signal is observed in sensors' data with a move-out depending on the arrival direction (top right picture).

I need to find the location of the signal source in an area mapped into grid cells surrounding the sensors. I am aware of array signal processing algorithms (beamforming, ...) for location estimation but I am trying to solve this as a least square problem.

Cross correlating sensor data (every sensor with its next) I find the delay between the observed signal's arrival times on sensors (3rd picture). Now, in the simplest scenario of homogeneous propagation velocity, say 2 km/s and using the observed time differences and the positions of the sensors, how do I set up my cost function and optimize so as to find the grid position most likely the source ? My problem is really the setting up of the cost function in Matlab.

In a more difficult scenario, where the velocity is changing across the grid, I need to calculate travel times from each sensor to every grid cell. I do that using a FD solver (see 4th and 5th pictures). Again, having the travel time grids, the observed time differences and the sensor positions, how do I find the most probable source ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: in a nutshell, a "cost" function can be best assembled when you have some prior knowledge about the theoretical behavior of your problem. Otherwise, you can try to fit some polynomial or similar. Once you have some function `f(x)` the cost is just sum(abs(f(x)-g(x))^2) where `g(x)` is your measured `d signal...

Comment: Hmm, the terms travel time inversion via least-squares and most likely source positon seem contradictory to me. The first is a deterministic inversion, the second a probabilistic. For the second case, it could be interesting to look into Coalescence Microseismic Mapping for the estimation of the most likely source position (and origin time): 
http://gji.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2013/09/12/gji.ggt331

Comment: Generally, I agree with bla, but in case you are dealing with error-contaminated data, you would want to divide the measurements by the approximate data error.

Comment: Thanks, this is a real good paper on the subject.

Comment: Yes, it is the case. The example above is a simplified case. The real data is very noisy and the signal to noise ratio low. In reality the number of sensors much higher. That's why I was thinking of optimization where the time residuals are minimized and the time differences for some of the sensors are very uncertain.